# Python beautifulsoup - get all text separated by break tag

Tags: python, string, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, replace

I have the following tables:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
                      <tbody><tr> 
                        <td class="labelplain">ANGARA, EDGARDO J.<br>ENRILE, JUAN PONCE<br>MAGSAYSAY JR., RAMON B.<br>ROXAS, MAR<br>GORDON, RICHARD "DICK" J.<br>FLAVIER, JUAN M.<br>MADRIGAL, M. A.<br>ARROYO, JOKER P.<br>RECTO, RALPH G.<br></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
```

I can traverse towards this part of the HTML using the following code below:

```
soup.find('td', text = re.compile('Co-author\(s'), attrs={'class': 'labelplain'}).find_next('td')
coauthor = soup.find('td', text = re.compile('Co-author\(s'), attrs={'class': 'labelplain'}).find_next('td')
```

I am able to get the text using the one below:

```
for br in coauthor.find_all('br'):
  firstcoauthor = (br.previousSibling)
  print (firstcoauthor)
```

The output I want to arrive to is a result of all text then separated by a semicolon (;) like so:
ANGARA, EDGARDO J.;ENRILE, JUAN PONCE;MAGSAYSAY JR., RAMON B.;ROXAS, MAR;GORDON, RICHARD "DICK" J.;FLAVIER, JUAN M.;MADRIGAL, M. A.;ARROYO, JOKER P.;RECTO, RALPH G.

But the code above gives me a result like below:

```
ANGARA, EDGARDO J.
ENRILE, JUAN PONCE
MAGSAYSAY JR., RAMON B.
ROXAS, MAR
GORDON, RICHARD "DICK" J.
FLAVIER, JUAN M.
MADRIGAL, M. A.
ARROYO, JOKER P.
RECTO, RALPH G.
```

I've tried the replace function but to no avail.

```
print (firstcoauthor.replace("\n", ";"))
```

and

```
print (firstcoauthor.replace("\r\n", ";"))
```

Even escape \r\n and \n like so:

```
print (firstcoauthor.replace("\\n", ";"))
```

How do I address my use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think it is much more simpler to get that result with setting join/delimiter parameter to `get_text()`:

```
soup.find('td').get_text(';')
```

Based on your example you will get:

```
ANGARA, EDGARDO J.;ENRILE, JUAN PONCE;MAGSAYSAY JR., RAMON B.;ROXAS, MAR;GORDON, RICHARD "DICK" J.;FLAVIER, JUAN M.;MADRIGAL, M. A.;ARROYO, JOKER P.;RECTO, RALPH G.
```

### EDIT

Based on the behaviour, extra semicolons, mentioned in your comment, I suspect that the structure of the element is different from the one in the question and has extra breaks.

In that case, I would change the strategy and recommend to:

- add additional `strip` parameter to `get_text()`:

  ```
  soup.find('td').get_text(';', strip=True)
  ```
- or use a `join()` from `stripped_strings`, what is doing almost the same:

  ```
  ';'.join(soup.find('td').stripped_strings)
  ```

###### Example HTML

Added additional `<br>`, spaces and linebreaks to the HTML.

```
html = '''
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody><tr>
    
    <br>
           <td class="labelplain">
           ANGARA, EDGARDO J.<br>ENRILE, JUAN PONCE<br>MAGSAYSAY JR., RAMON B.<br>ROXAS, MAR<br>GORDON, RICHARD "DICK" J.<br>FLAVIER, JUAN M.<br>MADRIGAL, M. A.<br>ARROYO, JOKER P.<br>RECTO, RALPH G.<br> 
           
           <br>
           </td>
           </tr>
</tbody></table>'''
```

###### Output

```
ANGARA, EDGARDO J.;ENRILE, JUAN PONCE;MAGSAYSAY JR., RAMON B.;ROXAS, MAR;GORDON, RICHARD "DICK" J.;FLAVIER, JUAN M.;MADRIGAL, M. A.;ARROYO, JOKER P.;RECTO, RALPH G.
```

Comment: I always forget `get_text()` can do this... this is definitely the way to go!

Comment: This is one of the rare cases where I use `get_text()`, otherwise I am lazy and just use `.text` probably like the majority here.

Comment: Thanks to you both Hedgehog and Jon Clements. With Jon Clements answer, I was actually getting extra space while Hedgehog, I am getting extra semicolon before and after like below. I am not sure where those extra spaces and semicolons are coming from but both answered what I want to do. ;
;ANGARA, EDGARDO J.;ENRILE, JUAN PONCE;MAGSAYSAY JR., RAMON B.;ROXAS, MAR;GORDON, RICHARD "DICK" J.;FLAVIER, JUAN M.;MADRIGAL, M. A.;ARROYO, JOKER P.;RECTO, RALPH G.;
;

Comment: @schnydszch Thanks a lot  for your comment, behaviour is based on a deviating html structure. Edited my answer, so you will get the expected result.

Comment: @HedgeHog Thanks for the update. I actually did the replace: output = output.replace('\n','') but for Jon Clements code. I guess yours would do with output.replace(';\n','') since it is already a string. But yeah, your answer - of adding "strip=True" is better. :)

Answer (score 4):

Select the element you want - I'm just picking the `td` here... (but use whatever so you have the element with the embedded `br` elements)

```
data = soup.select_one('td')
```

Then... replace all the `br` elements with a semi-colon:

```
for br in data.select('br'):
    br.replace_with(';')
```

Get your element's text:

```
output = data.get_text()
# 'ANGARA, EDGARDO J.;ENRILE, JUAN PONCE;MAGSAYSAY JR., RAMON B.;ROXAS, MAR;GORDON, RICHARD "DICK" J.;FLAVIER, JUAN M.;MADRIGAL, M. A.;ARROYO, JOKER P.;RECTO, RALPH G.;'
```

Comment: This did the trick. I didn't know "replace_with". This is simpler. I was even trying putting the results in array and iterating them over but to no avail. yours is KISS :)

Comment: @schnydszch I forgot about `get_text()` taking arguments... HedgeHog's answer is the way to go here for proper KISS :)